# Visual Studios 2010: 'File location'.exe is not recognized as internal or external command... (C program)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

My Thermo professor assigned our class a computational project in which we have to calculate some thermodynamic functions. He provided us with some code to work off of which is a program that essentially finds the area under a curve between two points for the function x^2. The code is said to be correct and it looks correct to me. However, I've been having FREQUENT problems with all of my programs giving me the error "'File location'.exe is not recognized as internal or external command, operable programs or batch files." upon initial running of a project or [mostly] reopening projects.

I've been researching the problem for many hours. I tried adjusting the environmental variables like so many other sites suggested, but I'm either not doing it right or it's not working. All I keep reading about is people explaining the purpose of an .exe file and that I have to locate that file and open that. The problem is that I cannot find ANY .exe file. There is the project I created with the source.c file I created and wrote the program in. Everything else has lengthy extensions that I've never seen before.

I'm growing increasingly impatient with Visual Studios' inconsistent behavior lately. I've just made the switch from MATLAB, which although is an inferior programming language, is far more user friendly and easier to program with. For those of you interested in the code I'm running, it is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
double integration();

double integration()
{
    int num_of_intervals = 4, i;
    double final_sum = 0, lower_limit = 2, upper_limit = 3, var, y = 1, x;

    x = (upper_limit - lower_limit) / num_of_intervals; // Calculating delta x value

    if(num_of_intervals % 2 != 0) //Simpson's rule can be performed only on even number of intervals
    {
        printf("Cannot perform integration. Number of intervals should be even");
        return 0;
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < num_of_intervals ; i++)
    {
        if(i != 0) //Coefficients for even and odd places. Even places, it is 2 and for odd it is 4.
        {
            if(i % 2 == 0)
                y = 2;

            else
                y = 4;
        }

        var = lower_limit + (i * x);// Calculating the function variable value
        final_sum = final_sum + (pow(var, 2) * y); //Calculating the sum
    }

    final_sum = (final_sum + pow(upper_limit , 2)) * x / 3; //Final sum
    return final_sum;
}

int main()
{
    printf("The integral value of x2 between limits 2 and 3 is %lf \n" , integration());
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Dom

Comment: Why do you have quotes in your filename? The rest of the question content seems irrelevant.

Comment: It's not actually the file name...The file location is lengthy and unnecessary so I just wrote 'File location' in its place to demonstrate what the error message is displaying. And I made my post detailed because I always see people complaining about the lack of information in the initial post, which requires the OP to keep replying. I figured if I gave as much information as I could initially, I would eliminate the confusion. Apparently it hasn't...Thanks for your useless comment and opinion though.

Comment: It would seem that the program fails to link, and therefore fails to execute the .exe, because it doesn't exist. You should have gotten some linker errors in that case. Since Visual Studio has such crappy standard compliance, I would download a real C compiler instead. For example [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). Then convert this non-standard code to standard C and compile.

Comment: What kind of project are you adding this file to? I just created a Win32 Console app in VS2010 and it compiled and ran with no issues. The only alteration I made was to add the lines in main() to the provided _tmain() function.

Comment: @ Malice I too am adding a Win32 console app. I then add a source file with the .c extension and create a program. Generally, any program I write works initially as yours did. When I reopen I click the file of this type in the desired folder: Microsoft Visual Studio Solution (.sln). This is when the program sometimes doesn't work, giving me the .exe error. Is that the wrong file to open? I've opened all other file types in the project folder and still got nothing.

Comment: Update: I pasted the code from the faulty program to a new project and source file and it worked fine. I then closed VS and reopened the .sln file...It also worked fine. However, as I said before this does not always happen. I wrote another code yesterday that successfully worked initially, but failed (.exe error) when reopened.